# How to determine if a double integral is convergent

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to determine if the following double integral is convergent in the first quadrant
$$ \iint \frac{1}{1+x^3+y^3} dx dy$$

I tried polar coordinates and got
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{r}{{1+r^3(\cos^3 \theta + \sin^3 \theta)}}\, dr d \theta$$

But it does not get any easier! Any tips to solve this type of questions?

Comment: On $[0,\pi/2],$ $\cos^3+\sin^3\ge C>0.$

Comment: Making the substitution $x=t^{2/3};\, y=s^{2/3}$ and switching to the polar system ($t=r\cos\phi;s=r\sin\phi$)
$$I=\frac{4}{9}\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+t^2+s^2}\,\frac{dtds}{(ts)^{1/3}}=\frac{2}{9}\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{(1+x)x^{1/3}}\int_0^{\pi/2}\big(\sin\phi\cos\phi)^{-1/3}d\phi$$
Both integrals can be expressed via Beta-functions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function